# how can i install kernel on centos7

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, linux-kernel, system-installation

​​hi.
I have a Centos7.but I want to install a specific kernel version like this.

```
3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.61.el7.x86_64
```

How can I install that version and boot from the above kernel?

Comment: That is a CloudLinux kernel - not a CentOS kernel.

Comment: Repo "baseurl" = https://www.repo.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux/6h/updates-testing/x86_64/ ......... → packages → https://www.repo.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux/6h/updates-testing/x86_64/RPMS/